# SQL Query to linked server just keeps on running

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 server and a `*.dbf` file that I would like to import into SQL Server. When I tested this on my dev machine I am able to query the `.dbf` file and import the data but for some reason when I try set this up on the remote site, I am not having any luck.

I have had to install the ACE.12 x64 files from MS for both.

On the remote server when I run my query, it just loops over and never really finishes.

My SQL code is below and running in SQL Server Management Studio

```
SELECT * FROM CARRIAGE2...DBLOG
```

I set up a linked server identical to my testing server

```
Provider: Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider
Product Name: Microsoft Jet (Tried Microsoft ACE)
Data Source: c:\Users\Stephen\Desktop
Provider String: dBASE 5.0
```

I know there are about 56000 records, and expect it to take some time, but have left it to run for 24 hours with no results.

How can I go about diagnosing and checking what's going wrong?

Comment: Is it a typo that you have 3 dots (...) between your db name and your table name in `CARRIAGE2...DBLOG`?  There should only be two correct?

Comment: I dont think 56K records should take 24 hours.  Unless you are over a 2400 baud modem moving porn movies. .. i remember those days...

Comment: Thanks, ill try again with only two, (hope that wasn't it), it's strange that it isn't even giving a result. just keeps on running